# Cannot see exception that caused termination in core dump

Tags: c++, exception, coredump

I have a multi threaded program written in c++ running on ARM.
I have enabled global core dump of applications by running:
echo "/var/log/core.%e.%t" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
ulimit -c unlimited

An exception is thrown in the program which isn't being caught.
I open the core dump that was generated using eclipse.
I expect to see the code that throw the exception in the callstack.
But I can't see it.

[image: Print screen from eclipse]

The rest of the callstack for the other threads look ok
I tried to manually change the $SP of the first line in the callstack to the address defined in the verbose termiate line:  0xb6eba0d8 but that cause the callstack to only show the syscall line

How can I see more lines in this thread's stack?

Comment: Sounds like your thread is in a library that doesn't have debug symbols built into it to me.

Comment: Could also be a damaged stack

Comment: The stack is most likely corrupted. So your best bet is to look at the raw stack. With gdb you can for instance see the top 10 elements with "x/10x $sp". Then you have to try to map the addresses to functions.

Answer (score 2):

There were two problems:

1. The stack was unwound. Until GCC 8 - When using std::thread, libstdc++'s function that calls the user's thread function contains a try/catch all statement. Using pthread instead solves this issue. See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55917 for details
2. I was using libstdc++ without debug symbols while trying to debug. The function that was called by the thread was compiled with debug symbols but that wasn't enough. I used the file command to see that the library inside /usr/lib didn't have debug symbols, so I used the libraries from my Linaro distribution installation which did have.